# How would I change the color of the for only one user in roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

So what I am trying to do is make a script that will change the color of what the user chats but the problem is it syncs for the other user.

```
local GamePlays = game:GetService("Players")

local GameChat = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("ChatServiceRunner"):WaitForChild("ChatService"))

local AdminNames = {"Road_Gamer2"}

local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")

GameChat.SpeakerAdded:Connect(function(PLRName)
    
    local Play = game.Players[PLRName]
    
    script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        
        local Speak = GameChat:GetSpeaker(Play.Name)
        
        Speak:SetExtraData("ChatColor",Color3.fromRGB(2, 152, 0))   

    end)
    
end)
```

Comment: what do you mean with it "syncs for the other user"? does the other user see the color or is the color applied to all players?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a local script file, the changes will only be made on the user's device. To run the server connections in the local script, you can look at the communication paths with https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Remote-Functions-and-Events.

Answer (score 0):

If the script is a server script then it will replicate to all players you can re-write the script in a local script and place it in Starter Player Scripts